# How to add a new option to select entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm working on a view with lots of invoices.

Users can filter them by 'Customer', 'Date' and also by **'Referent'**.

An invoice is linked to a customer, and a customer can have a 'referent' or not.

So in my 'referent' select list, the default value is 'All' to not filter by 'referent', and the rest is the list of all referents got by QueryBuilder.

Now, I need help to know how can I insert an option 'No Referent' in the select list to get all invoices for which the customer has no referent.

Here is my referent field in my 'InvoiceSearchType':

```
->add('referent', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
            'label' => 'Referent',
            'class' => 'GeocalUserBundle:User',
            'query_builder' => function (UserRepository $ur) {
                return $ur->getEmployesQueryBuilder();
            },
            'empty_value' => '',
            'configs' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'All',
                'width' => '100%',
                'allowClear' => true,
            ),
            'required' => false,
        ))
```

Here, my QueryBuilder:

```
public function getEmployesQueryBuilder()
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->leftJoin('u.groups', 'g')
                        ->where('u.enabled = 1')
                        ->andWhere('g.id NOT IN(1)')
                        ->orderBy('u.nom', 'ASC')
                     ;

    return $queryBuilder;
}
```

And I just display the field like that:

```
<td class="label">Chargé d'affaire</td>
<td colspan="2">{{ form_widget(form.referent) }}</td>
```

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: please show the corresponding template...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

First I added a method which get the result (array) of the query, add another referent and return it:

```
public function getReferentWithNull()
{
    // Get the list of referents
    $referents = $this->doctrine->getRepository('GeocalUserBundle:User')->getEmployesQueryBuilder()->getQuery()->getResult();

    // Create a new instance
    $nobody = new User();
    $nobody->setName("No Referent");

    // Put it in the array result with the key -1
    $referents[-1] = $nobody;

    return $referents;
}
```

Then, I modified my form field type to 'choice' type and call my previous function:

```
->add('referent', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_choice', array(
            'label' => 'Referent',
            'choices' => $this->getReferentWithNull(),
            'empty_value' => '',
            'configs' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'All',
                'width' => '100%',
                'allowClear' => true,
            ),
            'required' => false,
        ))
```

Finally, I have my last option 'No Referent' with a key of -1.

Hope that it helps someone :)